# GeoServer Plugin Dev Guide

Tags: geoserver, references

I was searching for some sort of a guide to develop a plugin on GeoServer, but couldn't find it.

Is there any good example I could study instead?

Comment: Start by looking at GeoTools, it has a dev guide with tutorials. With no understanding of GeoTools, you'll have a hard time working in GeoServer. After that, it all depends on what type of plugin you're trying to develop. Get into extensions and search for one that's similar to what you want, and use it as an example.